# <? not recognized as php delimiter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using xampp with php 5.6. I am developing a project using laravel and I encountered the following issue:

`<?` is not recognized as php delimiter within blade templating.

Comment: I think, you need to enable `short open tag`...

Comment: in your `php.ini` file change the setting `short_open_tag = on`

Comment: did you got any error..??

Comment: `<?` is a short open tag, if you can't enable it like hardik solanik said, you should use `<?php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official documentation:

> PHP also allows for short open tag `<?` (which is discouraged since it
>   is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini
>   configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the
>   --enable-short-tags option)

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php